# SignalR does not work in Firefox and IE but Chrome

Tags: signalr

im new in Signalr.

My project is need to simply update and show promocode to user instantly when staff update. This is working fine in Google Chrome but not in firefox and IE. There is no any error show to me.

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
        var hubNotify = $.connection.PromoCodeHub;

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            getData();
        });

        hubNotify.client.displayPromoCode = function () {
            getData();
        };

        $.connection.hub.disconnected(function ()
        {
            setTimeout(function ()
            {
                $.connection.hub.start().done(function ()
                {
                    getData();
                });
            }, 3000);  
        });
    });
```

This is my startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyProject.Startup))]
namespace MyProject
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
           app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Google Chrome: There is no issue when i update the promocode.

FireFox & IE: It will run the $.connection.hub.start().done() when the page is completely load. the rest wont work.

Your help is much appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, you need to have at least one client method declared before your start like below. Not sure about the differing browser behavior.

```
    var hubNotify = $.connection.PromoCodeHub;

    hubNotify.client.displayPromoCode = function () {
        getData();
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        getData();
    });
```